# Error Code: 1193. Unknown system variable 'action'

Tags: triggers

delimiter //
drop trigger if exists tr_overdue
//

create trigger tr_overdue 
-- type of trigger, etc
after update on invoice
for each row
    begin
    if status = 'overdue' then
    insert into alerts  values(new.message_date,new.origin,new.message);
  SET  action  =  'update',
    message_date = NOW(),
    origin=old.campaignno, message  = 'invoice with number ' + old.invoiceno + ' is now overdue';
   end if;
 end

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_overdue AFTER UPDATE ON Invoice FOR EACH ROW IF STATUS = 'overdue' THEN INSERT INTO alerts(columns1, column2,...) VALUES(new.message_date,new.origin,new.message);
```

I'm unsure if the columns you're updating in the SET statement also belong in Invoice, but if they do, then they should be included into the INSERT statement and that should fix the problem.